# Dividing polygons into equal parts by the number of points inside

Tags: qgis, splitting, equal-area

I would like to divide many polygons into 2, 3 or 4 parts.

I have vectorized plants. Sometimes 2, 3 or more plants hide under one polygon. Depending on the size I just have to divide the polygon into 2, 3 or 4 equal parts. Target is to set polygon centroids and count point (plants).

[image: example]

> Enhanced from a comment

Actually I only need points in the polygon depending on the size of the polygon.

- `Polygon size < 0.004m²` `=>` Single plant `=>` One point
- `0.004m² < Polygon size < 0.008m²` `=>` Two plants `=>` Two points
- `0.008m² < Polygon size < 0.012m²` `=>` Three plants `=>` Three points

It does not matter what position has the points in the polygon. They should only be within the polygon. In the end, I want to count the points in my field (that's easy)

Comment: What are your ideas by so far? What have you investigated? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you care about how the polygon will be split? Because there is more than one solution, check this [Can you divide this figure into two equal parts?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51225/can-you-divide-this-figure-into-two-equal-parts). If yes, can you also provide a closer view of how the points are distributed within the polygons? And what are your expectations?

Comment: Actually I only need points depending on the size of the polygon. A single plant has a polygon size of <0.004m² = 1 point.
Polygon size of> 0.004m² <0.008m² are two plants. Here I need two points in the polygon. Polygon size of > 0.008m² <0.012m² are three plants. Here I need three points in the polygon. It does not matter what position have the points in the polygon. They should only be within the polygon. At the end I want to count the points in my field (that's easy)

Comment: So, what do you actually need? Split your polygon into parts based on the number of points inside or just create points in the polygon depending on the size of the polygon?

Answer (score 2):

**Use the Field Calculator to add a new field, `"NumPlants"` with this expression:**

```sql
case 
  when $area <= 0.004 then 1
  when $area > 0.004 and $area <= 0.008 then 2
  when $area > 0.008 and $area <= 0.012 then 3
  when $area > 0.012 then 4
end
```

Notes:

- The `$area` function will calculate each polygon's area *in the layer's units of measure*. If your layer is not in an equal-area CRS with meters as its units of measure, you should re-project it. You can re-project it by saving the layer as a new file in the new CRS, or use the `transform` function inside the expression. Use this expression for the `$area` function in the previous expression (substitute the correct EPSG codes for your source and destination CRS's):

  ```
  area(transform($geometry,'EPSG:0000','EPSG:0001'))
  ```
- Notice that I made the upper end of each range inclusive by using the "greater than or equal" symbol instead of the "greater than" symbol. If both ends of each ranger were both exclusive (using the "less than" and "greater than" symbols), any polygons with areas of exactly 0.004, 0.008 or 0.012 would be excluded. You can make the bottom end of each range inclusive instead, like this: `$area >= 0.004 and $area < 0.008`. The important point is to set up the categories so that every possible input falls into one (and only one) category.

---

**Once you have the `"NumPlants"` field, use it to create that number of points in each polygon.** There are multiple ways to do this.

One way is with the "random points inside polygons" tool. Choose "points count" as the strategy, and use `"NumPlants"` as the expression. This method randomly places the points inside the polygon.

[image: example]

If you need more precise control over where the points are placed inside the polygon, use the "geometry by expression" tool. The only limitation on the level of control is your ability to write an expression to achieve the desired arrangement. Here's a simple example, which places the points at 10m distances from the centroid:

```sql
case 
  when "NumPlants" = 1 then $centroid
  when "NumPlants" = 2 then collect(make_point(x($centroid)+10,y($centroid)), make_point(x($centroid)-10,y($centroid)))
  when "NumPlants" = 3 then collect(make_point(x($centroid)+10,y($centroid)), make_point(x($centroid)-10,y($centroid)), make_point(x($centroid),y($centroid)+10)))
  when "NumPlants" = 4 then collect(make_point(x($centroid)+10,y($centroid)), make_point(x($centroid)-10,y($centroid)), make_point(x($centroid),y($centroid)+10)), make_point(x($centroid),y($centroid)-10)))
end
```